# Invalid character value for cast specification using dbWriteTable in R for pure character dataframe

Tags: r

I have a very simple dataframe, comprising only of "chr" variables.

When I try to commit to Oracle using dbWriteTable, I get an error:

> Error in result_insert_dataframe(rs@ptr, values, batch_rows) :
> nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1655: 00000: [RStudio][Support] (40550) Invalid
> character value for cast specification.

```
  people_df <- people_df %>% 
  rename(
    LAST_NAME      = sn,
    FIRST_NAME     = givenName,
    TITLE          = title,
    PRID           = cn,
    COUNTRY        = co,
    DEPARTMENT     = department,
    DISPLAY_NAME   = displayName
  )

dbWriteTable(con, "TEST_SHINY", people_df, append = TRUE)
```

Table definition in Oracle is as below:

[image]

Update:  Final code looked this, with a final SELECT statement, but main issue was the short length of the database columns....I increased these all to 200 chars, and this code worked.  I also mistyped TITLE, it should have been JOB_TITLE, but this wasn't causing the specific error.

```
people_df <- (people_df %>% 
  rename(
    LAST_NAME      = sn,
    FIRST_NAME     = givenName,
    JOB_TITLE      = title,
    PRID           = cn,
    COUNTRY        = co,
    DEPARTMENT     = department,
    DISPLAY_NAME   = displayName
  ) %>% select(LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, JOB_TITLE, PRID, COUNTRY, DEPARTMENT, DISPLAY_NAME)
)
```

Comment: Check your data.  Maybe your R dataframe has UTF-8 characters and the Oracle table will not support it.

Comment: We know nothing of the target table. Please post the output from `"select column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length, character_set_name, collation_name from information_schema.columns where table_name='TEST_SHINY'"`. (I'm assuming Oracle supports that table, it's common among many ...)

Comment: Done....they are all VARCHARS that are being inserted, I am avoiding dates for now

Comment: `DBI` supports `Date`-class objects natively, I would not expect an error there. BTW, `TITLE` or `JOB_TITLE`?

Comment: Also, have you checked your string lengths? Perhaps `sapply(people_df, function(z) max(nchar(z)))`?

Comment: If all columns in the query are varchar than the error may be due to an encoding mismatch. You can obtain the character set of an Oracle DB by executing `SELECT * FROM v$nls_parameters WHERE parameter LIKE '%CHARACTERSET'` Then when you create your connection via `dbConnect` you can explicitly specify character encoding by passing in the appropriate `encoding` argument.

Comment: I think it was related to my short varchar lengths in the database, thanks all....I'm an idiot

Comment: @br00t NLS_CHARACTERSET=AL32UTF8, NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET=UTF8

Comment: Did changing the lengths of your VARCHAR columns resolve the issue @smackenzie or are you still having issues?